# Load functions/mappings etc in vim only when working in a specific repo

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to know if it's possible to setup vim in a way that when I am working in a certain repo, it will load additional functions/mappings etc.

Like ftplugin with file types, but the type is not defined by the file itself but by its location (or by the result of a command, e.g. hg path default).

Comment: Note: there is a dedicated [stackexchange Vi site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oops I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean a certain repo? how do you decide it? by path? or what?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, yes path works for me, and also the result of a command works for me (e.g. hg path default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for your need, but it is just an example.

```
augroup repo
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufReadPost * call RepoMappings()
augroup END

function! RepoMappings()
    let repo = '^/tmp/test/'
    if expand('%:p') =~# repo
        nnoremap <buffer> <f7> :echo 'yohoo'<cr>
    endif
endfunction
```

You change the `let repo = '^/tmp/test/'`, which would be the `prefix` of your repo path. In the above example, only for files in your "repo", the `<f7>` mapping works.

You can extend the `repo` variable to a list, or for different repo call different functions...

One thing is not handled, if you open a new buffer, without filename, you may want to check the `pwd` to see if it is in the "repo".  But you got the idea, you can impl. it on your own if it was required.

Just give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

### Central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>